# Is there actually a chrome bug in css transitions?

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, css-transitions

Please look at this codepen I made (in chrome) some months ago. At this time the transition easings worked fine. But now (in chrome 34) these easings are looking very weird. All other browsers are looking fine.

http://codepen.io/philippkuehn/pen/cEoxl?editors=110

Is this a known bug? I've found nothing about that.

Comment: I think it's related to the values set on `cubic-bezier(.5, 1.5, .55, 1)` function: `1.5` is out of range (see http://cubic-bezier.com/)

Comment: Yes I know. The point is that this bezier worked in chrome some versions ago and in all other browsers.

Comment: And the bezier cubic-bezier(.65,1.95,.03,.32) is out of range too but is working fine in chrome.